# How to get rid of exec()

Tags: python

Is there a way to use something other than exec() and to make this shorter/look more pro?

```
for list_ in lists_to_activate:
    for widget in list_:
        exec(
            '{1} = tk.Label({0}, text="{2}", background="{3}", fg="{4}", font={5})'.format(widget[0],
                                                                                           widget[1],
                                                                                           widget[2],
                                                                                           widget[3],
                                                                                           widget[4],
                                                                                           widget[5]))
        exec('{}.pack({})'.format(widget[1],
                                  widget[7]))
        exec('{0}.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, self=self, object={0}: self.button(object, "{0}"))'.format(
            widget[1]))

        if widget[6] == 1:
            exec('{0}.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, self=self, object={0}: self.is_focus(object, True))'.format(
                widget[1]))
            exec(
                '{0}.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, self=self, object={0}: self.is_focus(object, False))'.format(
                    widget[1]))
```

This is how lists_to_activate looks like. lists_to_activate is a list of lists

```
HEADER_WLIST = [
                ['self.header_frame', 'self.title', 'EVIL MARKET ANALYZER', 'black', 'white', '("FuturaBookC", 21)', 0,
                 'side="left",padx=35,pady=13'],
                ['self.header_frame', 'self.settings', 'settings', 'black', 'white', '("FuturaLightC", 22)', 1,
                 'side="right",padx=20,pady=10'],
                ['self.header_menu', 'self.menu_1', '  TODAY  ', '#ff402f', 'white', '("FuturaBookC", 35)', 1,
                 'side="left", fill="both", expand = 1'],
                ['self.header_menu', 'self.menu_2', '   NEWS   ', 'white', 'black', '("FuturaBookC", 35)', 1,
                 'side="left",fill="both", expand = 1'],
                ['self.header_menu', 'self.menu_3', '  TWITTER ', 'white', 'black', '("FuturaBookC", 35)', 1,
                 'side="left", fill="both", expand = 1'],
                ['self.header_menu', 'self.blank', ' ', 'white', 'black', '("FuturaBookC", 0)', 0,
                 'side="left",pady=25'],
                ['self.header_menu', 'self.menu_4', 'CONCLUSION', 'white', 'black', '("FuturaBookC", 35)', 1,
                 'side="right", fill="both", expand = 1']
]
CNBC_WLIST = []...
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use callbacks on the widget.

Comment: Could you please show an example of what  `widget` looks like ?

Comment: @Programmer here you go

Comment: This seems like you're designing things wrong from the beginning. You should basically never use `exec` or `eval` in a Python program. And it seems to stem from you defining code as a list of strings, which isn't a good idea. You need to rethink your whole program and write code instead of strings. It's hard to give a specific answer as it's not clear how your program works outside of this code snippet, other than try looking at defining/use classes and maybe dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Warning of `exec` or `eval`

Whenever you use `exec` or `eval`, you should reconsider what you're doing, as those functions should almost never be used. Using them indicates a severe design flaw as code and data becomes the same thing, when they should be separated. Code is logic, and data is data.

If you start coding using either of those functions, it's going to be hard to change your design afterwards. So avoid them from the beginning!

### What to do instead

It's hard to know the solution for your specific problem, so I had to guess. But this shouldn't be too different from what you could do.

First, create a class that contains the actual data you want to operate on, with good names. This makes things clearer as you'll write `widget.text` instead of `widget[2]`.

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, text, background, foreground, font, config, is_focusable):
        self.text = text
        self.background = background
        self.foreground = foreground
        self.font = font
        self.config = config
        self.is_focusable = is_focusable
```

Then create a function that encapsulates the logic, i.e. the common operations, and pass in the relevant data.

```
def create_label(frame, widget, parent):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=widget.text, background=widget.background, fg=widget.foreground, font=widget.font)
    label.pack(**widget.config)
    label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, self=parent, object=label: self.button(object, label.__name__))

    if widget.is_focusable:
        label.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, self=parent, object=label: self.is_focus(object, True))
        label.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, self=parent, object=label: self.is_focus(object, False))
    
    return label
```

Store the data in a proper data structures. It seems like you're trying to create labels for some frame. Using a dictionary allows you to associate a name (like the name of your attribute) with some data.

```
WIDGET_LIST = [
    'title':    Widget('EVIL MARKET ANALYZER', 'black', 'white', '("FuturaBookC", 21)', False, {'side': "left", 'padx': 35, 'pady': 13}),
    'settings': Widget('settings', 'black', 'white', '("FuturaLightC", 22)', True, {'side': "right", 'padx': 20, 'pady': 10})
    # And so on...
]
```

Then you can do iterate over the dictionary and use our function to create labels. This assumes that you use a dictionary `self.labels` instead of individual attributes like `self.title`, `self.menu_1`, `self.settings`, and so on...

```
for name, widget in WIDGET_LIST.items():
    self.labels[name] = create_label(self.header_menu, widget, self)
```

### Full code

```
class Widget:
    def __init__(self, text, background, foreground, font, config, is_focusable):
        self.text = text
        self.background = background
        self.foreground = foreground
        self.font = font
        self.config = config
        self.is_focusable = is_focusable


WIDGET_LIST = [
    'title':    Widget('EVIL MARKET ANALYZER', 'black', 'white', '("FuturaBookC", 21)', False, {'side': "left", 'padx': 35, 'pady': 13}),
    'settings': Widget('settings', 'black', 'white', '("FuturaLightC", 22)', True, {'side': "right", 'padx': 20, 'pady': 10})
    # And so on...
]


def create_label(frame, widget, parent):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=widget.text, background=widget.background, fg=widget.foreground, font=widget.font)
    label.pack(**widget.config)
    label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, self=parent, object=label: self.button(object, label.__name__))

    if widget.is_focusable:
        label.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, self=parent, object=label: self.is_focus(object, True))
        label.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, self=parent, object=label: self.is_focus(object, False))
    
    return label

# Then use this in your class which contains the different labels, don't have this globally.
for name, widget in WIDGET_LIST.items():
    self.labels[name] = create_label(self.header_menu, widget, self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getattr` and `setattr`:

```py
for list_ in lists_to_activate:
    for widget in list_:
        cur_wid = tk.Label(getattr(self, widget[0].replace("self.", "")), text=widget[2], background=widget[3], fg=widget[4], font=widget[5])
        cur_wid.pack(widget[7])
        cur_wid.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, self=self, object=cur_wid: self.button(object, widget[1]))

        if widget[6] == 1:
            cur_wid.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, self=self, object=cur_wid: self.is_focus(object, True))
            cur_wid.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, self=self, object=cur_wid: self.is_focus(object, False))
        setattr(self, widget[1].replace("self.", ""), cur_wid)
```

Comment: `self[...]` won't work "like a dictionary" in this sense, unless the particular class has `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods which do what you're expecting them to do. I think you want `self.__dict__[...]` instead.

Comment: Perhaps a cleaner and self-documenting alternative would be to use `getattr(self, widget[0].replace("self.", ""))`. Then you'd also get an `AttributeError` if it doesn't exist instead of `KeyError`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I considered using that, but had some reason why I wouldn't use that, which I forgot by now !